# how to take the value[ ] inside a child in firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Inside my code I have a line of code in which it should fetch the value of **userID** inside the child "*profilepicture*" that is inside the child "*users*" in Firebase Database but I don't know how to write this inside value[ ]. Could somebody help me ?

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value,         
    let users = DataSnapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    self.user.removeAll()
    for (_, value) in users{
        //let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        if let uid = value["profilepicture.userID"] as? String
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

Your node `users` seems to be an Array. So it's heavily depend upon which user's `userID` you want to set. So using your code the attempt must like following

```
let dbQuery = dbRef.child("users")
dbQuery.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            if  let dataSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                let valueDict = dataSnapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                // here valueDict is each user as dictionary
                // here you will need a mechanism to identify the user
                // of which you want to set the `userID` value
                let key = dataSnapshot.key // each users key

                if /* your logic to identify the user based on the key. If this logic satisfy then set it's value */ {
                       dbRef.child("users").child(key).child("profilepicture").child("userID").setValue(YOUR_DESIRED_VALUE_TO_SET)

                   // OPTIMIZATION: if this meant to happen only once use `break` to get out of the loop, because you don't need to iterate the whole loop.
                } 
            }
        }
        print("YOU ARE DONE UPDATING")
    })
```